# System.Indexoutofrangeexception error not understood

Tags: c#, matrix, indexoutofrangeexception

Hi i am a beginner at c# and i did not understand why the exception is thrown at the program shown below

PROGRAM:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n, i, x=0, y=0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the degree of matrix:");
            n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[,] num = new int[n, n];
            int p = n * n;
            for (i = 1; i <= p; i++)
            {
                num[x, y] = i;
                if (num[x, y] % n == 0) { y++; }
                if (y % 2 == 0) { x++; }
                if (y % 2 != 0) { x--; }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    Console.Write(num[i, j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

REQUIRED RESULT:

```
Enter order of matrix:
4

1 8 9  16
2 7 10 15
3 6 11 14 
4 5 12 13
```

But an exception as stated in the topic is thrown at num[x ,y]=i; . I do not understand why System.IndexOutOfRangeException occurs as the loop clearly ends at the end of the 2d array.

P.S. the program is meant to run only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong, but if you insert 2 as degree of the matrix, the variable p equals 4.

The external for cycle

```
for (i = 1; i <= p; i++)
```

cycles 4 times, from 1 to 4. But when i == 4, X equals -1, and you cannot access a matrix with negative index. You get the same behavior with degree = 4, like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You must not change your `x` value in the same loop iteration where you change the `y` value because doing that, you don't fill the last position in the second column and subsequently iterate down to `x = -1` which is an invalid index.

```
    for (i = 1; i <= p; i++)
    {
        num[x, y] = i;
        if (i % n == 0) { 
            y++; 
        }
        else {
            if (y % 2 == 0) { x++; }
            if (y % 2 != 0) { x--; }
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            Console.Write(num[i, j] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one: you made just a basic mistake, here x is decrement at time of y increment, using continue statement skip loop after increment y, I guarantee this working 100%.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n, i, x = 0, y = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the degree of matrix:");
            n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[,] num = new int[n, n];
            int p = n * n;

            for (i = 1; i <= p; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    num[x, y] = i;
                    if (num[x, y] % n == 0) { y++; continue; }
                    if (y % 2 == 0) { x++; }
                    if (y % 2 != 0) { x--; }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(num[i, j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```